# List processes for specific user

Tags: c++, api, winapi

Would someone be able to point me to the C++ API's that I can use to display a list of processes and the user name in Windows?

My current code uses the CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Function which shows all the processes running for all users, but I do not know what API's to use to retreieve the user name so I can filter it by user.  I do not need to use CreateToolhelp32Snapshot, and I have seen other methods to retrieve the process list, but none seem to get me the user name that is running the process.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that using GetTokenInformation with TokenUser gets you the SID, and a quick serach reveals that LookupAccountSid should get you the corresponding account. Havent't tried that last one myself though.

Answer (score 2):

Well [this link](http://win32.mvps.org/security/opt_gti.cpp) appears to have helpful code for you.  Apply the code contained there in to the Token handle you get from calling OpenProcessToken on the handle you get from Process32First/Next.